# Angular7: Template parse errors: The pipe 'titlecase' / 'slice' could not be found

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template, angular7

I'm migrating my app from **Angular 6** to **Angular 7**

After running ng update , and updating my packages , things goes well until i run:

```
ng build --configuration=production
```

it seems that it can't find some angular well known pipes : **titlecase** / **slice** :

```
ERROR in : Template parse errors:
The pipe 'titlecase' could not be found ("span class="nav-item border-left text-truncate px-2 text-left">
    <span class="text-capitalize">{{[ERROR ->]username | titlecase }}</span>
    <span class="text-capitalize">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="text-"): /media/khalidvm/SecondDisk/SOCLE_RCD/Front/Frontend_v3_crmd/src/app/Features/CRMD/navbar-crmd/navbar-crmd-components/navbar-crmd/navbar-crmd.component.html@14:36
The pipe 'slice' could not be found ("ecase }}</span>
    <span class="text-capitalize">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="text-capitalize">{{[ERROR ->]userlastname | slice:0:1}} </span>
    <span class="text-capitalize">&nbsp;</span>
    <span>-</span>"): /media/khalidvm/SecondDisk/SOCLE_RCD/Front/Frontend_v3_crmd/src/app/Features/CRMD/navbar-crmd/navbar-crmd-components/navbar-crmd/navbar-crmd.component.html@16:36
```

My component looks like this :

```
<div id="HeaderNav" class="nav bg-white mx-auto py-1 d-flex  flex-nowrap">
  <span class="nav-item dropdown mx-1">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="icon svg-avatar"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item disabled">Profil Conseiller</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="srcdPiloteViewAccess" (click)="goSrcdView()">Devenir Pilote</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" *ngIf="administrationViewAccess" (click)="goAdministrationView()">Devenir Administrateur</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" (click)="logout()">Se déconnecter</a>
    </ul>
  </span>
  <span class="nav-item border-left text-truncate px-2 text-left">
    <span class="text-capitalize">{{username | titlecase }}</span>
    <span class="text-capitalize">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="text-capitalize">{{userlastname | slice:0:1}} </span>
    <span class="text-capitalize">&nbsp;</span>
    <span>-</span>
    <span class="text-capitalize">&nbsp;</span>
    <span class="text-capitalize">boutique orange {{shopName}}</span>
  </span>
  <span class="nav-item text-truncate text-center en-attente">
    <!--<span class="nav-item">4 personnes en attente</span>-->
  </span>
  <span class="espace-vide"></span>
</div>
```

Thefore i ve verified my module **NgModule** , and i'm well importing the **CommonModule**

But when when building the app , they are missing

**Suggestions ?**

Comment: I have suggestions : **post your code and a [mcve]**.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem. With a little digging I found out it has something to do with [having Ivy enabled](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26436) in your TS config.

What I did to solve it is **remove** the following configuration from the `tsconfig.json`:

```json
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true
}
```

Comment: i ve imported this option , and still have same issue

Comment: removing it leads to another error Error: No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency