# After upgrading from Angular5 to Angular7, slice pipe is going into infinite loops

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7, angular-pipe, ng-upgrade

I have upgraded my project from angular 5 to angular 7. After upgrading to latest, slice pipe is not working as expected. It is going into infinite loops in the angular core files. My browser screen also got struct in the same page.

> *ngFor="let hero of heroes | slice:0:3;"

When I removed the slice pipe and use *ngIf, page is woking fine.

```
<div *ngFor="let hero of heroes;let i=index"><div *ngIf="i<3"></div></div>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Can you share the code for the slice Pipe?

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example in stackblitz, this helps the SO community to better answer your question

Comment: code is same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53430659/angular7-template-parse-errors-the-pipe-titlecase-slice-could-not-be-fou

Comment: created a stackblitz repository in 
>>https://angular-75kaqz.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 0):

remove ; from slice use like this *ngFor="let hero of heroes | slice:0:3"

Comment: Still no luck:(